# python tornado: encode and decode about url

Tags: python, utf-8, tornado, utf

I'm building a web server with tornado. You can search key words and get reply from the server.

User can type any word such as Chinese or Japanese, so I know that I should use UTF-8.

Here is my core code:

```
class SearchHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, path):
        try:
            print(self.get_argument('key'))
            print(urllib.parse.unquote(self.get_argument('key'))
            val = urllib.parse.unquote(self.get_argument('key'))
            ...
            ...
```

Now let's say that an user searched a Chinese word: 泰国
The two `print` will give me the result as below:

```
%E6%B3%B0%E5%9B%BD
泰国
```

At the backend part, I'll use `泰国`.

For now everything's fine.

Today I find some weird words in my log:
`country-cn.html?æ³°å½content`
[image]

Then I copy it into my browser, it show as it looks like:
[image]

However, I send the log file to a Windows and open it as `txt`, it shows a Chinese word: 泰国.

I'm totally confused now. I use my PC (Mac OS) and type `泰国` to visit my web server, everything's fine. But it seems that some guy was trying to search the same Chinese word with a special encoding way that I don't know so I couldn't decode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that some browsers will default to non-UTF-8 encodings when they can (I'm not sure that's what's happening here because it's most common for `latin-1` encodings). Putting a hidden input in your form with a field that can only be represented in UTF-8 will force the browser to use that encoding:

```
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
```